How to use BitsAllocated and PixelRepresentation to read image
I am using dcmtk to read dicom. In this dicom, the BitsAllocated=16, and PixelRepresentation=1. It means the type of pixel data is a signed int 16. Then, I use e->getSInt16Array(pImg) to read DCM_PixelData, but the pImg is a null pointer. However, e->getUint16Array(pImg) give a good pImg, and it shows correct image after I change pImg to int16: (signed short)pImg.
My question is: why e->getSint16Array(pImg) failed for BitsAllocated=16, and PixelRepresentation=1, but e->getUint16Array(pImg) succeed?

In DICOM, the Pixel Data (7fe0,0010) element is stored with a Value Representation (VR) of "OB" (8 bit unsigned integers) or "OW" (16 bit unsigned integers), i.e. getSint16Array() does not apply. This method is part of DCMTK's dcmdata module, which does not deal with details of the pixel data encoding, such as sign extension.
If you want more sophisticated support for DICOM images, you should consider using DCMTK's dcmimgle/dcmimage module.

What is the tag name of Value Representation? I can not find it in dicom header.

The VR is not encoded as a separate Data Element, so there is no Attribute Tag associated with it. The VR is rather part of each Data Element, i.e. it is encoded in the byte stream of a DICOM Data Set (if not omitted for Transfer Syntaxes like Implicit VR Little Endian). DCMTK allows for retrieving information on the VR of each Data Element, e.g. by calling getVR() on the respective instance of DcmElement.

Thanks for your kindly reply. I need to learn more dicom.
